# Unable to Single Sign Out or Federation

Tags: spring-security

I am using spring security Saml 2.0.I ran the sample application provided by spring security
(idp.ssocircle.com as identity provider).And it is running successfully.
Now I am tring to implement it in my application .
my application is redirecting successfully on idp and asking for username password.After putting credentials it is giving error message "unable to single sign out or federation" on  idp.ssocircle.com site .I am unable to get control it to my application .